# SQL INDEX WITH ONLINE = ON

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, azure-sql-database

I have created a index on SQL Azure Where Query works perfectly fine and Index is created successfully but with an exception `ONLINE = OFF`

My Query to Create Index:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [nci_wi_tbl_transactions] ON [dbo].[tbl_transactions] (
[bank_account_id]) INCLUDE ([bankcode]) WITH (ONLINE = ON)
```

When viewing the index in table is like this:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX nci_wi_tbl_transactions ON dbo.tbl_transactions (  bank_account_id ASC  )  
     INCLUDE ( bankcode ) 
     WITH (  PAD_INDEX = OFF ,FILLFACTOR = 100  ,SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF , IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF , STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF , ONLINE = OFF , ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON , ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON  )
     ON [PRIMARY ]
```

If you notice the above Index is created with `ONLINE = OFF`

I am trying to figure out why it is creating index with `ONLINE = OFF` instead of `ONLINE = ON`, Is it possible to create non-clustered index with `ONLINE = ON`. If yes how can I create index with `ONLINE = ON`

Am I missing something here.

Comment: *"When viewing the index in table is like this:"* What do you mean by "viewing" the index?

Comment: @Larnu I mean I am viewing the created Index source.

Answer (score 1):

`WITH (ONLINE = ON)` is a property of the `CREATE INDEX` statement, not of the index that gets created.

Hypothetically, two `CREATE INDEX` statements that were identical except that one had `WITH (ONLINE = ON)` and the other had `WITH (ONLINE = OFF)` would result in the creation of *exactly the same index*.

Answer (score 0):

The metadata simply doesn't track *how you created it* because that is an operational / runtime attribute that does not become a permanent property of the index. It would be like a row maintaining information about what recovery model the database was in when the row was added.

> Can you explain this little more, so I can find a solution to this issue.

I mean that when you create an index SQL Server doesn't remember whether you did so using `ONLINE = ON` or `ONLINE = OFF`. So when you view the properties or generate a new script from SSMS, it's always going to be OFF. People have used other workarounds, like manually scripting the indexes, including checking if the index *can* be built online (by manually adding `ONLINE = ON`), and always doing so if it is possible. For example:

- [Script out all SQL Server Indexes in a Database using T-SQL](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3441/script-out-all-sql-server-indexes-in-a-database-using-tsql/?utm_source=AaronBertrand)

Or, if you are generating the scripts from SSMS, you can simply manually change the output and try `ONLINE = ON` always, just be prepared that sometimes that option is not possible.

Comment: Can you explain this little more, so I can find a solution to this issue.